# dense_rank with setval on serial column (query in PSQL 13)

Tags: postgresql, dense-rank, postgresql-13

I'm trying to insert data in a table named `test` defined by the following schema:
`CREATE TABLE test (s INTEGER, p INTEGER, o INTEGER, id SERIAL NOT NULL)`

Then I run this query to set the start value for the column `id`: `SELECT setval('test_id_seq', 12)`

Finally I insert with this query: `INSERT INTO test SELECT s, p, o, dense_rank() over (order by p) from test;`

The problem is that I obtain the following:

```
 s | p | o | id
---+---+---+----
 4 | 6 | 2 |  1
 5 | 6 | 8 |  1
 4 | 7 | 3 |  2
 5 | 7 | 1 |  2
```

Instead of:

```
 s | p | o | id
---+---+---+----
 4 | 6 | 2 | 13
 5 | 6 | 8 | 13
 4 | 7 | 3 | 14
 5 | 7 | 1 | 14
```

**How can I make the dense_rank() function starting at my `'test_id_seq'`?** I'm using PostgreSQL 13.

Comment: Use expression `dense_rank() over (order by p) + currval('test_id_seq')`. Please note that  sequences do not obey transaction rules.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Stefanov.sm

The solution is to use `dense_rank() over (order by p) + currval('test_id_seq')` in the insert statement.